# Click on button icon acts strange

Tags: jquery, button, click

I have a problem with clicking on the submit button, actually the icon on the button. It fires the submit event however when checking the server side post vars resulting from the ajax call the "btnUpdate" post var is not set when the icon is clicked:

```
   <button type="submit" name="btnUpdate" id="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa-fw fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Update</button>
```

The output of the server side php serialize($_POST):

1. Clicking the icon on the button: a:1:{s:4:"hkey";s:3:"7e1";}
2. Clicking the button: a:1:{s:4:"hkey";s:3:"7e1";s:9:"btnUpdate";s:0:"";}

Notice that the "btnUpdate" is not present in the first instance where the icon on the button is clicked.

Comment: *"Code works fine"* - What code?  Please provide a minimal and complete example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Do not name anything submit in a form

Comment: @ David: I have provided more info

Comment: How can you click on the icon of the button without triggering the button click? Do you have a handler for the icon on top of the submit button? Seems like the form is submitted twice, once because it is a button of type submit, and then because there is a click handler on icon that is sending only certain input fields (excluding  button, of course)

Comment: @boze: How are you posting the data to the server?  What "AJAX call" are you referring to in the question?  The question is tagged with jQuery, what does that have to do with what's being asked or where is that code?  In your browser's debugging tools, what data is being posted to the server in each case?

Comment: @ David, thanks for assisting so far. I had difficulty in getting the structure of the question right and your comments have guided me in my quest. I'll update the question in the morning and try and be as specific as possible. At the end of the day the issue is that the submit button "btnUpdate" does not post the button data  to the post array when the icon is clicked within the button, no other click binding is done in this specific instance. I'll submit all the relevant code tomorrow.

Comment: @ Nawed Khan - in this case it is a pure submit button, not other click events are bound to the button. But the results are the same if I add bound clicks. I must highlight the I'm using font-awesome 4.7 as the icon in the botton